# Mongoose/NodeJS - Is there a way to skip a middleware?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using my `save` method to **save** and **update**. For my registration page I have a method `pre("save")` which checks whether or not the user already exists.

Because of this I can't use save to update anymore.

My current approach is to check if certain properties of the object have changed (those that can't be set in registration page) and if so, I can "trick" skip the `pre("save")` method. But this is no way near clean. If I like to change the username for example (which is accessible from registration page) I couldn't do it.

I come up with this, instead of filtering within the `pre("save")` method:

```
user.save(function(error){
    if( error.name != "UserAlreadyExistError")
```

Comment: Some code sample will certainly help both the users who answer, and yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

When I do:

```
var user = new UserModel();

user.save()
```

Mongoose will check if there is a user with the given `_id`, and if so will throw a duplicate key error.

However, when the user is retrieved within the `findOne()` method and **then** saved, it won't throw any duplicate keys error, as if mongoose knows that it is an intented update.

Also note, that the field `_id` has to be **exactly** called like this.